# Singelton cluster in K-means sql server ssas

Tags: sql-server, ssas

Am trying to analysis dataset which contain almost 50,000 records. I used the analysis server and setting algorithm to K-means. But the problem is that the majority of the record is going to one cluster ( almost 48,000 record ). Whereas, when I cluster it in different application such as SPSS, it gave me acceptable result. I prepared the data set and remove the outliers but the problem is still not solved. So, just I wanna ask if there is any idea to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this technical documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280445.aspx) article. According to it, the default setting of the "normalization" parameter assumes a normal distribution of the data; if this is not  the case you should change this setting.

I cannot be sure if this is your issue, though... A thorough reading of this documentation could reveal other differences between the two algorithm implemetations as well.